# For what values of $a$ does the system $x^2=y^2$ and $(x - a)^2 + y^2 = 1$ have exactly zero, one, two, three, or four solutions?

Tags: geometry

> For what values of $a$ does the system of equations $$x^2 = y^2$$  $$(x - a)^2 + y^2 = 1$$ have exactly zero, one, two, three, four solutions, respectively? (Hint: Translate the problem into an equivalent geometry problem.)

I can solve this problem with just algebra, but I want to understand what the hint is trying to teach me.

So far, I have considered areas of squares which add up to $1$ and the existence of right angle triangles for values of $a$ whose hypotenuse is $1$.

I'd appreciate any help but please I don't want the problem to be completely spoiled. Thank you for your time.

Comment: in the $xy$-plane, $(x-a)^2+y^2=1$ is a circle, and $x^2=y^2$ is lines intersecting at the origin

Comment: Yeah, that the first thing I noticed, but how would that lead to a solution?

Comment: And $x^2=y^2$ means the lines $y=x$ and $y=-x$.

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/0ogsjmids1

Comment: @SagarM, Atticus Yeah I've also considered that, but the way to solve for $a$ would eventually be algebraic right? I have even graphed it on desmos

Comment: I just realized that my dumbass had actually solved the problem. The first thing I did was visualize the equations and notice that the $a$ translates the circle. I was hang on finding a geometrically equivalent problem to $x^2+(x-a)^2=1$ (after subtituting $x^2$ for $y^2$). Funny enough I was testing my guesses based on my solution using the circle translation. Ahhh. I thought this problem had something much more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in comments, one equation is a circle of radius $1$, with a parameter $a$ that controls where the center of the circle sits on the $x$-axis; the other equation is a pair of lines.  Try visually sliding the circle along the $x$-axis to see what the possible intersection patterns are.

Answer (score 0):

I like how you think about it. I think the additional geometric insight is that the tangents are perpendicular to each other and the moment you take this into account, there is no algebra needed, only trigonometry and geometry.